# адаптер для ListView

Tags: java, android

есть адаптер для listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/cost_button"
           android:id="@+id/imageView3"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:id="@+id/text_time"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:text="r"
          android:textColor="@color/list_background"
          android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:id="@+id/text_cost"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:text="r"
          android:textColor="@color/about"
          android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text_time"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_time"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/text_nametrain"
          android:textSize="20dp"
          android:text="fffffffffff"
          android:textColor="@color/about"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_time"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:visibility="invisible"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/text_stations"
          android:textColor="@color/name"
          android:textSize="25dp"
          android:text="rrrr"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        />
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/how_often"
          android:textColor="@color/list_divider"
          android:text="rrrr"
          android:textSize="25dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        />
```

есть вывод в listview

```
 ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
        //Загружаем в него результат работы doInBackground
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ScreenTwo.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  output));
```

вопрос: как вывести в адаптер данные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html

В методе getView указывается, что куда записывать.
Он вызывается каждый раз, когда требуется отобразить элемент списка, который ранее был за пределами видимой части ListView